# Passing python data to php webserver Apache

Tags: php, python, apache

I have this code that gets the temperature from a sensor in python(raspberry pi)

```
import time
def getTemp(str):
        tempfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000dw4adcc/w1_slave")
        thetext = tempfile.read()
        tempfile.close()
        tempdata = thetext.split("\n")[1].split(" ")[9]
        temperature = float(tempdata[2:])
        temperature = temperature / 1000
        print temperature
getTemp(0)
```

Now how do I pass it to a index.php file that is on the apache server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write that to a database using python and read it with PHP.
The easiest way is probably to write in a file :

Python :

```
f = open('/tmp/temperature.txt', 'w')
f.write(temperature)
f.close()
```

PHP :

```
$temperature = file_get_contents('/tmp/temperature.txt');
```

Comment: OMG, I did not even think about that. Thank You!

Comment: It won't work we need to convert it to a string first the temperature,

Comment: z = str(temperature) and then write that